# Is the relation < necessarily a total order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

Let $M$ be a non-empty set, $+$ a binary operation on $M$, and $<$ a relation on M, satisfying the following:

1. For all $a, b, c \in M$, $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$
2. For all $a, b \in M$ with $a \ne b$, exactly one of $a < b$ and $b < a$ is true.
3. For all $a, b \in M$ with $a < b$, at least one of the equations $a + x = b$ and $x + a = b$ has a solution for $x$ in $M$.
4. For all $a, b \in M$ with $a < b$, neither of the equations $b + x = a$ nor $x + b = a$ have a solution for $x$ in $M$.

The question is: is it necessarily true that for all $a, b, c \in M$, that if $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$?

Comment: looks tough, did you come up with this yourself?

Comment: @HereToRelax Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the oriented graph with vertex set $M$ in which edge $(a,b)$ exists if $a<b$.

Label each edge $(a,b)$ of this graph with the label $L$ if $x+a=b$ has solution.

Label each edge $(a,b)$ of this graph with the label $R$ if $a+x=b$ has solution.

Note each edge has at least one label.

Assume there is a triangle cycle $a\rightarrow b\rightarrow c\rightarrow a$. Such a cycle must contain two consegutive edges with the same label, so we can rotate it so that without loss of generality the first two arrows have the same label. without loss of generality the label is $L$.

We have $b=x+a$ and $c=y+b$ and so $c=y+x+a$ which means $a<c$ which is a contradiction, as we assumed $c<a$

Comment: Looks correct to me, nice work! I am also curious where this problem originated from.

Comment: @MikeF I came up with this on my own, because I'm studying a related algebraic structure in my personal (for fun) work, where both x + a = b and a + x = b must have a solution if a < b (I asked a question last August about them). I was hoping the answer to this question was no, but since it is a yes that means I will have to start studying this more general structure.

Comment: I found an answer by Eric Wofsey on that question. Very interesting stuff.